# JDeveloper and gradle integration

Tags: gradle, jdeveloper

I am completly new in Oracles JDeveloper.

I am looking at different IDE alternatives, does JDeveloper have any form of gradle support?

Comment: https://better-coding.com/adf-and-gradle-integration-part1-assembling-adf-project-using-ojdeploy-1/

Comment: Great, looks like a way, thx !